# Including calib3d gives many compilation errors

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use [`cv::Rodrigues`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga61585db663d9da06b68e70cfbf6a1eac) function in order to get a rotation matrix from a given vector of angles.

I already have these includes in my program:

```
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
```

Without adding `#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"` everything compiles just fine.
But when I add it in order to be able to use `cv::Rodrigues` the compilation fails with many errors.

I won't add the whole error log because it will be long and useless. But it starts with this:

```
<command-line>:0:9: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
<command-line>:0:9: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
<command-line>:0:9: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

And after that I have many error such as :

```
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp:1106:69: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
                                const Scalar& color=Scalar::all(-1), int flags=DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );
                                                                     ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp:1130:32: error: variable or field 'drawMatches' declared void
 CV_EXPORTS_W void drawMatches( InputArray img1, const std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints1,
                                ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp:1130:32: error: 'InputArray' was not declared in this scope
```

For completeness here is the part of the code that I would like to add:

```
void test(cv::Matx33f& rot_mat){

    float x =  50 * (M_PI/180);
    float y =  -10 * (M_PI/180);
    float z =  0 * (M_PI/180);

    cv::Matx31f rot_vec(x,y,z);

    //converts to a rotation matrix
    cv::Rodrigues(rot_vec, rot_mat);
}
```

Note: I am working on Ubuntu 15.10 with OpenCV 3.1.0 and I did add `-lopencv_calib3d` to my makefile.

Comment: Please provide part of the source associated with the errors.

Comment: There errors are due to adding `calib3d.hpp` . I have a working c++ with opencv code that compiles and runs just fine. When I add `calib3d.hpp` in order to be able to use `cv::Rodrigues` I get those error, even without changing any of my code.

Comment: Including a file changes the code the compiler sees.  Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Per Stack Overflow:   Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Calib3d has runtime dependencies on features2d, Flann, ImgProc and Core, can you try including the missing headers

Comment: Thanks, I have added the part of the code I want to add to the program, but with it or without it I get the same bunch of errors.

Comment: @EdChum I just tried what you suggested but still same errors appears.